# Image processing in C

Tags: c++, c, image-processing

I found a book on **image processing in C**: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/PHILLIPS/

The case is that I'm willing to use C++ for image processing. Do you think it would be fine reading this book willing to use C++ instead of C or prefer a book that describes image processing using C++?

If the later, what books or resources do you recommend for that?

Thanks.

Comment: Any ideas on this book? "A Concise Introduction to Image Processing using C++" http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584888970

Answer (score 3):

While you might use some classes to make your code more idiomatic in C++ you can transfer most of the algorithmic knowledge you learn. And image processing is mostly algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

The book will describe mostly algorithms. Even the implementations, you could get the gist of it and implement again in C++ without too much trouble. I wouldn't worry about it if you have a basic C grasp.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually I don't have C grasp, and just learning C++ to apply it in image processing.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you could think C++ and C languages are different. What you can do in C++ is completely different from what you can do in C, because available libraries are designed in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get from point A to point B and you have an example of how to do it in C, then by all means use C.  The user isn't going to notice.  If, on the other hand, you are trying to learn C++ techniques at the same time, then C examples aren't going to help much.  Personally, I'd just use the C example and document the header well so that it can be called later by whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You will be able to use this book to add image processing to your C++ app, because you can compile C and C++ in the same project.

If you want to convert the samples to C++, you'll probably want to rewrite them from scratch: C++ has useful features that allow you to define and use your own complex numbers or other high level constructs that make the code readable. I have not seen a book that shows how to do this in C++, would be interested if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

I think taking this approach is quite a good idea. C is very close to being a subset of C++, so you may find that all the code compiles fine in C++ as it is. Any issues should be easy enough to resolve and teach you the difference.

You can then proceed to C++-ise incrementally:

- Change free functions into member functions
- Move declarations from the start of blocks to the point of use and make them initialisations
- See if there is any natural polymorphism and use it to create a class hierarchy
- etc.

Such as incremental approach gives you a meaningful application to play with while you bring in more complex concepts.

Go for it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Does this apply also if one does not have knowledge in C?

Comment: Much of the key code for image processing is going to be quite quite low level. So the key code in C++ you'll want to learn to do this will be fairly C-like in any case, so whether or not you know C you will have to acquire C knowledge. I think that is a good language for image processing, so in short: Yes.